# Why does the following three printf statements print the same value?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, memory-address

```
int data[2][2] = {1,2,3,4};
int (*p)[2];
p = &data[0];
printf("%d\n",p);
printf("%d\n",data[0]);
printf("%d\n",&data[0]);
```

In this program the value of data[0] and &data[0] returns the same answer. Can anyone provide the explanation?

Comment: your tags answer the question itself. "reference", "pointer", "memory-address"

Comment: You already equated the first and third with `p = &data[0];`